# Get XML Element with JDOM

Tags: java, xml, saml, jdom

I have a XML file like the following one.

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                    Destination="https://hostname.example.com:4444/fed/idp/samlv20"
                    ID="id-OPIfhD3il2eK816THPlj2Nk38KM-"
                    IssueInstant="2014-09-02T14:36:02Z"
                    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                    Version="2.0"
                    >
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                 Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity"
                 >https://federation.example.com/sp</saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true"
                        Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified"
                        />
    <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
        <saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

How can get the content "https://federation.example.com/sp" from the above XML using JDOM ?

I am trying the below code and able to retrieve the "IssueInstant" & "ProtocolBinding" successfully. But unable to retrieve the content "https://federation.example.com/sp". Please help.

```
private String[] getRequestAttributes(String xmlString) throws SamlException {
      Document doc = Util.createJdomDoc(xmlString);
      if (doc != null) {
        String[] samlRequestAttributes = new String[2];
        samlRequestAttributes[0] = doc.getRootElement().getAttributeValue(
          "IssueInstant");
        samlRequestAttributes[2] = doc.getRootElement().getAttributeValue(
          "ProtocolBinding");
        return samlRequestAttributes;
      } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>   private String[] getRequestAttributes(String xmlString) throws SamlException {
>       Document doc = Util.createJdomDoc(xmlString);
>       if (doc != null) {
>         String[] samlRequestAttributes = new String[2];
>         samlRequestAttributes[0] = doc.getRootElement().getAttributeValue(
>           "IssueInstant");
>         samlRequestAttributes[2] = doc.getRootElement().getAttributeValue(
>           "ProtocolBinding");
>         return samlRequestAttributes;
>       } 
>   }
> ```

The above code is not going to work, because of a few reasons. For a start, the `samlRequestAttributes[2] = ...` line will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception because there is no index value 2. You should use index 1.

You do not indicate where you would want to store the value `https://federation.example.com/sp`, but I assume you would want it in the return array somewhere (perhaps at index 1?).

The way to retrieve it is to use namespaces for XML correctly.

Consider the following:

```
  private String[] getRequestAttributes(String xmlString) throws SamlException {
      Document doc = Util.createJdomDoc(xmlString);
      if (doc != null) {
        Namespace saml = Namespace.get("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
        String[] samlRequestAttributes = new String[3];
        Element root = doc.getRootElement();
        samlRequestAttributes[0] = root.getAttributeValue("IssueInstant");
        samlRequestAttributes[1] = root.getAttributeValue("ProtocolBinding");
        samlRequestAttributes[2] = root.getChild("Issuer", saml).getText();

        return samlRequestAttributes;
      } 
  }
```

Note how you need to identify the Namespace for the child element, and retrieve it from the root document with the correct namespace in the getChild call.